# How can i customize Bootstrap 3 Datepicker to only date without timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 Docs plugin:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I want the only date in view and the backend how can I achieve it.?
[image]

I'm not able to find proper documentation.
i want to hide these two marked timestamp details.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
  });
</script>
```

This might help you to get only date.

Comment: i have edited above answer please try this. This will give u exactly what u need